# Can I use more cores to speed up visual studio code's compliation of npm start?

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm-start

While running NPM Start within VS Code I get the following CPU usage.  The task takes about a minute to run.  Is it possible to get it to run at 100% on all cores?
[image: ter?]

Comment: Javascript is Single Thread by design, so no multi core possible

Comment: not even in the compilation?

Comment: The translation to intermediate code is only a small fraction of the total run time